# Can't upgrade 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: nvidia, upgrade

I did all obvious steps like:

- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo apt upgrade`
- `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

It just stops for like 5 minutes at step "nvidia-driver-530" and then aborts.

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,267 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,267 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'jammy.tar.gz' against 'jammy.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'jammy.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                
Get:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                             
Get:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]                           
Hit http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                
Hit https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease      
Fetched 222 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                   
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-driver-530

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

I already tried:

- update nvidia drivers
- delete nvidia drivers
- use nouveau drivers
- delete all drivers for gpu and do it from recovery mode
- change sourcelist for drivers
- use update-manager

Comment: That command sequence will only get all available upgrades for 20.04, not upgrade you to 22.04.  Which are you actually attempting?

Comment: @ZeissIkon
im trying upgrade to 22.04

Comment: Don't you want to use graphical update-manager?

Comment: @Mahler if you mean gui for update-manager, i tried already and it stops at same spot

Comment: check if the snapd.service is running. `systemctl status snapd.service`

Comment: @nobody OMG Thanks you very much, it helps, i reinstall snapd and enable it with systemctl

Comment: It might help others if you put everything below “Problem Solved” in an answer to your own question. 24 hours later you can accept your own answer

Comment: @ponjar thanks for advice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @nobody, for fixing this issue i do next steps:

- reinstall snapd:

  `sudo apt remove --purge snapd`

  `sudo apt install snapd`
- enable it with systemctl:

  `sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.service`